# How to view Keyboard Shortcuts cheat sheet in Unity on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I want to see the Keyboard Shortcuts list, but I don't know how to bring it up. How can I view it?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean Settings → Keyboard → Shortcuts ?

Comment: i mean the window with shortcuts like [this](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-bMC0vd9XOmo/T5Zj-mW9QyI/AAAAAAAAIpM/lAkaakNoPfU/s1600/ubuntu12.04-shortcut-hints-overlay.png)

Comment: Which flavour do you have? Ubuntu with Unity as in the screenshot?

Comment: Maybe you turned the option off. Though that can only be done in ccsm (compizconfig-settings-manager) or dconf-editor. Do you have either of these installed?

Answer (score 1):

To display the keyboard shortcuts, hold the "Super" key--most likely the Windows key, unless you have a Mac, in which case I don't know.

Comment: No, I haven't a Mac. 
Yes, I know about "Super" key. But in version 16.04 must be other command.

Comment: This site says it's still the same: http://www.beopensource.com/2016/05/keyboard-shortcuts-for-Ubuntu-1604-Xenial-Xerus.html  Are you not using Unity, as someone asked above about the flavor?

Comment: laur34, no, I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
Ty for this site, it may be helpful for me.

Comment: What Desktop Environment are you using? [This article](https://www.howtogeek.com/163154/linux-users-have-a-choice-8-linux-desktop-environments/) includes 8 of the most common environments, with screenshots to help you identify it. The reason why people are asking you if you're using Unity is because that is the default for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but it's easy to change. You tagged your post Xubuntu and Lubuntu - Xubuntu uses XFCE, and Lubuntu uses LXDE. Do either of those look familiar?

Comment: @invzbl3 “If you press _and hold_ the Super key, an overlay showing many of Unity's keyboard shortcuts appears until you release the Super key.” ([source](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/windows-key.html)) – Did you try **holding** the windows key?

Comment: sry, dekstop environment - Unity. I'm new user so...

Comment: @invzbl3 I think we figured ;-) – welcome in the Ubuntu family! A list of shortcuts is available [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-keyboard-shortcuts.html).

Comment: @dessert, pressing and holding Super key doesn't open keyboard shortcuts board, but show numbers on sidebar icons (t on trash can)

Comment: @Redbob That's really weird, I assumed [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/windows-key.html) would know… oO

Comment: I found this: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2211817, it seems Unity Cheat Sheet (it is the name) stopped working. I applied this solution to my box and nope.

Comment: @invzbl3 It seems like if you have four workspaces in a 2x2 grid enabled, the Cheat Sheet will not work – a weird bug. Does it work for you with a different workspace configuration?

Comment: @invzbl3, it worked on 17.04, even with workspaces actived and dual-monitors!! Video driver issue?