# Can not type a folder path in the 'folder hierarchy bar'

Tags: nautilus, 18.04, ubuntu-gnome

Say that I want to open this folder : `/usr/share/background`. When I open **Files** (*nautilus*) and try to write the path of the folder that I want to open, I can not. And there is no option in the menu to enter the location/path of the folder I want to open.
Is there a solution to fix this?

**Ps:** I know that I can open **Files>Other Locations>Computer**, but it is not practical and it is annoying to do it everytime I want to open a folder not listed under `/home`.

Comment: `Ctrl` + `L` works for me.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me (To make it beneficial for others too, please post it as an answer). But I didn't know about it before, is there a guide for shortcuts used in 18.04?

Comment: You used to be able to press and hold the `Super` key and get a cheat sheet of keyboard shortcuts. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/947204/how-to-view-keyboard-shortcuts-cheat-sheet-in-unity-on-ubuntu-16-04. For various reasons this no longer works for some people, in any case not for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that there are two answers to this problem:

1. **First answer** (easy one): Thanks to [@Jos](https://askubuntu.com/users/149708/jos)
   It just needs to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> while *nautilus* is open, then it will be possible to type/enter the path of the folder.
   [image]
2. **Second answer** (the hard one):
   If you are really fed up with *nautilus*, the solution is to install another File Manager like Nemo or Dolphin.